# Keeping page breaks from form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, line-breaks

In my Rails app, I want to keep the `\n` that are inputted in the forms. What I've done so far is output with `simple_format()`. But the problem is that simple_format wraps the text in < p >< /p > if there is a `\n`. This is problematic for my chatroom log as I don't want each message to appear in a new paragraph.

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
text.gsub("\n",'<br/>')
```